# Parsing JSONArray with Double in Android Studio

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to parse `JSONArray` from a MySQL Database in Android Studio, but i get the following exception:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"success":false,"0":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"1":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"2":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"3":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null}} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

What i am trying to do is to parse several markers containing double values for LatLng, and then placing those markers in Google Maps.

Code for placing the markers and making the request:

```
Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {

                            JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(response);
                            Log.i("RESPONSE:", "[" + jsonResponse + "]");


                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                                //boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                                //double lat = jsonResponse.getDouble("lat");
                                //double lng = jsonResponse.getDouble("lng");
                                //int snippet = jsonResponse.getInt("snippet");



                                //LatLng Mplace = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                                //MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(Mplace).title("Marker").snippet("Snippet:" + "0");
                                //mMap.addMarker(marker);


                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.i("RESPONSE:", "[" + response + "]");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }

                };

                MarkerRequest markerRequest = new MarkerRequest(responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(AllMarkersActivity.this);
                queue.add(markerRequest);
```

For now i have commented the actual placing of the markers and that is when i get the exception shown above. When i remove the commenting i get this red-text message:

```
getDouble (int) cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)
```

Here is my Request code:

```
public class MarkerRequest extends StringRequest {
private static final String MARKER_REQUEST_URL = "http://simonjensen.comxa.com/GetMarkers.php";
private Map<String, String> params;
//private JSONObject data = new JSONObject("http://simonjensen.comxa.com/GetMarkers.php");

public MarkerRequest(Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Request.Method.POST, MARKER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
}
@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

And here is my PHP script:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("myhost", "myuser", "mypass", "mydatabase");

/*$statement = mysqli_prepare($con);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM markers   ORDER BY marker_id  ASC ";
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM `markers`  ORDER BY marker_id  ASC ";

$objQuery = mysql_query($statement, $strSQL) or die(mysql_error());
$arrRows = array();
$arryItem = array();*/

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM markers    ORDER BY marker_id  ASC ");
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
//mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $colmarker_id, $collat, $collng, $colsnippet);

//$response = array();
$arrRows = array();
$arryItem = array();
    //$response["success"] = false;
$arrRows["success"] = false;
$arryItem["success"] = false;

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
    $arryItem["marker_id"] = $arr["marker_id"];
    $arryItem["lat"] = $arr["lat"];
    $arryItem["lng"] = $arr["lng"];
    $arryItem["snippet"] = $arr["snippet"];
    $arrRows[] = $arryItem;
}

echo json_encode($arrRows);
?>
```

So my question can be narrowed down to this:

How do i parse a `JSONArray` (within an array?), and how do i parse a double value within that `JSONArray`?

It would be nice with a code example, as i am still learning :)

Thanks!

Comment: your json does not contain array it has objects within a single object .Array  is represented by " [ ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your response contain JSON Object and the outer JSON object contain inner JSON objects. So, first parse it in JSON Object then get Lat and lng. Try this code:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
    while( keys.hasNext() )
    {
        String key = keys.next();
                if(!key.equals("success")){   // or use this if your keys are always in digits form.. if(TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(key))
                    Log.v("category key", key);
                    JSONObject innerJObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject(key);
                    String lat_str = innerJObject.getString("lat");
                    double lat = 0.0, lng = 0.0;

                    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(lat_str) &&      TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(lat_str))
                        lat = Double.parseDouble(lat_str);

                    String lng_str = innerJObject.getString("lng");

                    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(lng_str) && TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(lng_str))
                        lng = Double.parseDouble(lng_str);

                }
    }
```

Add exception handling in this block. This might help!

Comment: I tried this and got the exception: org.json.JSONException: Value false at success of type java.lang.Boolean cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: I have edited my answer now check. This because as we have "success" is not a key its a boolean. So, now check and let me know :)

Comment: Or you can use this TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(key) instead of !key.equals("success") if you think that your keys is always is in a digit form.

Comment: Okay, so i did this, and i think this works! Thanks! I marked this answer as accepted as i am fairly sure this does the trick. I am getting a choreographer log that says: "I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." which tells me that it's probably loading too much (which means it must work i guess). Just gotta figure out how to do it in background thread now :) Thanks!

Comment: Welcome bro!! feeling happy after your appreciation. And to test properly add some proper date in your JSON response then you will get the idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(response);
```

TO

```
 JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
```

getting lat value use following.

```
 double lat = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("0").optDouble("lat");
```

Comment: I already tried to do that, but then i get: org.json.JSONException: No value for lat   - which made me think i had to do aprse JSONArray

Comment: Thanks! That ''sorta'' made it work, it doesn't give me any exceptions now, but i am still getting null values in my JSONresponse. What gives? the response is like this, and places the markers in the middle of gmaps: I/RESPONSE: {"success":false,"0":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"1":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"2":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"3":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null}}

Comment: what null you are getting?

Comment: @SimonA.CallaghanJensen you should accept the answer first if its correct.

Comment: Well doing this removed the JSON exception, but i am still not parsing the data correctly. Like my comment before, i am getting null values parsed. The database doesn't contain null values, so the values must be parsed wrong somehow still. I don't know if it's my php that is wrong then, but the question is still unanswered, but closer to an answer :) The answer is still useful!

Comment: now can you post your code how you are parsing the data?

Comment: All of the code i am using is in my original question :) I am using PHP to do a query of my database, the script is in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are passing string data and not a double value. Try to do this:

```
 String lat_str = jsonResponse.getString("lat");
 double lat = Double.parseDouble(lat_str);
 String lng_str = jsonResponse.getString("lng");
 double lng = Double.parseDouble(lng_str);
```

Comment: I tried doing this both with JSONArray and JSONObject, with array it give me the same red-text as with double, just like this: getString (int) cannot be applied to (java.lang.String) and with JSONObject it gives me: org.json.JSONException: No value for lat

Answer (score 0):

```
try {

                JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(response);
                Log.i("RESPONSE:", "[" + jsonResponse + "]");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);



                    boolean success = obj.getBoolean("success");
                    double lat = obj.getDouble("lat");
                    double lng = obj.getDouble("lng");
                    int snippet = obj.getInt("snippet");


                    LatLng Mplace = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(Mplace).title("Marker").snippet("Snippet:" + "0");
                    mMap.addMarker(marker);


                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("RESPONSE:", "[" + response + "]");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: This seems to remove the red-text errors, but i still get the JSON exception: org.json.JSONException: Value {"success":false,"0":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"1":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"2":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null},"3":{"success":false,"marker_id":null,"lat":null,"lng":null,"snippet":null}} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: response = "[" + response + "]"; 
add this line before JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(response);

and in loop update start point 
 for (int i = 1; i < jsonResponse.length(); i++)

Comment: Just like the two other answers, i am pretty sure this works aswell, as I am getting a choreographer log that says: "I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." which tells me that it's probably loading too much (which means it must work i guess). Just gotta figure out how to do it in background thread now :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {

        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(json);


        boolean flag = true;
        int i = 0;
        while (flag) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonInnerObject = new      JSONObject(jsonResponse.get(String.valueOf(i)).toString());
                Object success = jsonInnerObject.get("success");
                Object marker_id = jsonInnerObject.get("marker_id");
                Object lat = jsonInnerObject.get("lat");
                Object lng = jsonInnerObject.get("lng");
                Object snippet = jsonInnerObject.get("snippet");
                i++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                flag = false;
            }


        }



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i("RESPONSE:", "[" + response + "]");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
```

Comment: When i do this i don't get any RESPONSE logged in logcat. It however doesn't give me any exceptions. How would i go aboyt placing the markers with this method? Thanks!

Comment: @SimonA.CallaghanJensen i didn't do anything with response that is why its not showing,,, if you debug this you are getting lat lon and other values from response in while loop ,,, you can do whatever you want to do here with values

Comment: I did this and just like the other answer I am getting a choreographer log that says: "I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." which tells me that it's probably loading too much (which means it must work i guess). Just gotta figure out how to do it in background thread now :) Thanks!

Comment: You can use aysncTask() for this purpose